# VBA Using Buttons Containing Pre-built Sentences to Build a Message About a Discussion with a Client

Tags: excel, vba

Complete noob here.  I work for a company where I take phone calls all day and after completing the call I need to document my discussion.  I find myself typing the same thing over and over and I'm trying to create a solution using VBA in Excel.  I cannot utilize outside programs so I'm stuck on VBA.  Below is my code.  The goal is to allow a user to click various buttons to build a message covering the topics of the call.  I'll then add the ability to copy the message which can then be pasted into the program we use for documenting notes.

As of current:

- I'm able to pull from two columns in a table on excel which create buttons for each row (column 1) and when I hover over the buttons I can see the desired text (Column 2), however, clicking the buttons does not display text in the textbox.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Class1

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Btn As MSForms.CommandButton


Private Sub Btn_Click()
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & Btn.Tag & " "
End Sub
```

UserForm1

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

Option Explicit

Private Btns As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim DataList As ListObject
    Set DataList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim btnTop As Long, btnLeft As Long
    Dim btnHeight As Long, btnWidth As Long
    Dim btnSpace As Long
    Dim ColCount As Long, CurrentCol As Long
    
    btnTop = 6: btnLeft = 6
    btnWidth = 72: btnHeight = 24
    btnSpace = 6
    ColCount = 4: CurrentCol = 1
    
    Set Btns = New Collection
    Dim cmdbtn As CommandButton
    Dim btnEvent As Class1
    Dim itm As Range

    For Each itm In DataList.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    Set cmdbtn = Me.Controls("Frame1").Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With cmdbtn
            .Top = btnTop
            .Left = btnLeft
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Height = btnHeight
            .Caption = itm
            .Tag = itm.Offset(, 1)
            .ControlTipText = .Tag
            
        End With
        Set btnEvnt = New Class1
        Set btnEvnt.Btn = cmdbtn
        Btns.Add btnEvnt
        
        btnLeft = (btnSpace + btnWidth) * CurrentCol + btnSpace
        
            If CurrentCol Mod ColCount = 0 Then
            CurrentCol = 1
            btnTop = btnSpace + btnTop + btnHeight
            btnLeft = btnSpace
            
            Else
                CurrentCol = CurrentCol + 1
            End If
            Next itm
            
            Me.Frame1.ScrollHeight = btnTop + btnHeight + btnSpace
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you didn't post a follow up to my reply on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/i9mb50/using_multiple_buttons_to_create_a_customized/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share). The `Userform_Click` line should be throwing a compile error.

Comment: Besides what @DarrenBartrup-Cook has mentioned, there are a few issues with your code which will throw errors (you declared `Dim btnEvent As Class1` but then you are initialising it as: `Set btnEvnt = New Class1`.. they don't match) . Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Sorry @Darren Bartrup-Cook! You helped me extensively and I personally struggle when it comes to asking for additional help when someone has already gone above and beyond anything that I could've expected.  Additionally I do not have access to Reddit on my work computer and wouldn't have been able to post the code that you typed up for me.  You are correct that it's throwing an error but given my extremely thin level of knowledge, it makes it easier to show how I input your code to ID any issues!

Comment: I'm presuming you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere. Try adding `On Error Goto 0` at the start of your form initialise and see what you get

Comment: @Zeewowski, sorry.  Didn't mean my comment to sound harsh. I never mind answering following up questions - doesn't mean I always will, depends where I am and if I remember when I get somewhere where I can check my answer. :)  The correction Zac gave should make the form work.  Do you intend other code to use in the form click event?  If not you can leave it out completely.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook No worries :)  It did, thanks for asking!  

I misunderstood his initial mention and was overthinking "they don't match".  My dumbass didn't initially interpret that as being incorrectly spelled!  Thank you both again!  Is it possible to up vote you guy son here?

Comment: Don't worry about the up vote. Glad it helped to resolve the issue

Comment: Hello again.  Things are going great and thanks again for all your help!  I did have a follow-up question.  You code allows me to input text into two columns.  Column 1 allows me to input the text for each button and column two is the text input into the textbox once clicked.  Two of my buttons allow for a user to input a ",' or "." when desired.  I noticed that it's automatically inputting a space before each and I didn't know if there was an easy way to prevent this?  I'm about 2 hours deep in googling and cannot find a solve.  Any help would be much appreciated but not expected.  Thanks!!